# Whats the best way to handle subdomains in a sitemap?

Tags: html, xml, web, seo, sitemap

If you have a website www.yourdomain.com and a subdomain blog.yourdomain.com 
(both sites containing simular information) what is the best sitemap setup?

Is it best to have one site map for both sites?
(and if so what would this look like?)

Or two separate sitemaps?

Which would be most effective in regards to search traffic optimisation?

Comment: How similar is the content?  This will make a big difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the content is identical, use a rel tag to tell Google (and the other search engines) which URL should be used to accrue page rank.

If you don't Google will split your page rank 'juice' over both pages.  Ideally, you want to concentrate your juice on one URL as it will get a better page rank.

Choose the main site or the subdomain to produce your site map for. IT doesn't really hurt anything if you do both.

The [rel="canonical"](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394) tags go in your html pages.

Comment: Thanks Will what will this look like in the xml?

Comment: I added a bit of clarity to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create single sitemap as:

http://yourdomain.com/sitemap.xml and define sitemap for all your blog posts urls under this sitemap.

This sitemap will help you to index a large archive of content pages of your blog.yourdomain.com. In this way, Google crawlers can index from a single place within less time.